# Create service in docker-compose.yml base on running container

Tags: docker

I have a docker and multiple services inside. But not every running container is in *docker-compose.yml*. For example here is my *docker-compose.yml* file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and running container

```
testtesttest        plugin-test:latest          "/entrypoint.sh"         11 months ago        Up 25 hours         0.0.0.0:3002->80/tcp   dockerfiles_plugin-test_1
```

Now I would like to add service with this container to *docker-compose.yml* file.

I know I can run *docker inspect testtesttest* to see details but what is the best way to recreate a service in *docker-compose.yml* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every service you define in your `docker-compose.yml` corresponds to a container that docker-compose will start and manage. You can't "add an existing container" to a compose file.

If you want your compose services to interact with an existing container, you can certainly do *that*. The easiest mechanism is to ensure that your compose containers are on the same network as the existing container. For example, assuming you have an existing network named `mynetwork` (created with `docker network create mynetwork`), you would start your non-compose service like this:

```
docker run --network mynetwork ...
```

And you would write your compose file like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      mynetwork: {}

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

This defines `mynetwork` as an *external* network -- that is, one that has been created outside of Docker compose. By putting your compose containers on the same network as your existing container, they will be able to refer to eachother by name. That is, if your existing container is named `dockerfiles_plugin-test_1`, then your db will be able to connect to it using the hostname `dockerfiles_plugin-test_1`.

If you want to go in the other direction and have the `dockerfiles_plugin-test_1` connect to the database, you probably want to set a static hostname (or alias) for the database container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - db

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

This gives the `db` container the hostname `db` on network `mynetwork`.